# kwic in quanteda (R) does not identify more than one word in regex pattern

Tags: r, regex, quanteda

I am trying to identify regex patterns in text, but kwic() does not identify regex phrases that are longer than just one word. I tried to use `phrase()`, but that did not work either.

To give you an example:

```
mycorpus = corpus(bla$`TEXT` )
foo = kwic(mycorpus, pattern = "\\bno\\b", window = 10, valuetype = "regex" ) #gives 1959 obs. 
foo = kwic(mycorpus, pattern = "\\bno\\b\\s{0,5}\\w+", window = 10, valuetype = "regex" ) #gives 0 obs.
foo = kwic(mycorpus, pattern = "no\\sother", window = 10, valuetype = "regex" ) #gives 0 obs. even though it should find 3 phrases
```

even though there are multiple patterns in the text that should be identified.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because kwic searches tokens, and tokens no longer contain spaces.  To search for a sequence of tokens, what quanteda treats as a "phrase", wrap the pattern in `phrase()`.  (See also `?phrase`.)

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.0

txt <- "one two three four five"

# no match
kwic(txt, "one\\stwo", valuetype = "regex", window = 1)
## kwic object with 0 rows

# match
kwic(txt, phrase("one two"), valuetype = "regex", window = 1)
##                                 
##  [text1, 1:2]  | one two | three
```

Comment: Thank you @Ken Benoit! That almost solves my problem. How come that "\\s" in the regex pattern does not work but a normal white space does? 
Match:
```kwic(mycorpus, pattern = phrase("others \\."), window = 10, valuetype = "regex" )``` 
no match: 
``` kwic(mycorpus, pattern = phrase("others\\s\\."), window = 10, valuetype = "regex" )```
Also, do you know how I would be able to retrieve patterns that work with repetition operators? So for example: 
```kwic(mycorpus, pattern = phrase("no \\w+")```
only gives me phrases with 1 word after "no", even though it should give me all 1+ words.

Comment: `phrase()` considers sequences of tokens, so if you want to match two consecutive tokens, and your second is ".", then you need to specify `phrase("others .")` (for `valuetype = "glob"` here).

Comment: How can I search for regex patterns like this then:           
`phrase("hello (friends|dear audience)") valuetype="regex"`