# Quanteda and stringr in R: (Correct) regex cannot be parsed

Tags: r, regex, escaping, stringr, quanteda

I want to run a regex search using the `quanteda` and `stringr` libraries, but I continue to receive errors. My goal is to match the patterns `(VP (V.. ...)` using the regex `\(VP\h+\(V\w*\h+\w*\)`. Here is a MWE:

```
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

text <- "(ROOT (S (NP (PRP It)) (VP (VBZ is) (RB not) (VP (VBN transmitted) (PP (IN from) (: :) (S (VP (VBG giving) (NP (NP (NP (NP (NML (NN blood)"


kwic_regex <- kwic(
  # define text
  text, 
  # define search pattern
  "\(VP\h+\(V\w*\h+\w*\)", 
  window = 20, 
  # define valuetype
  valuetype = "regex") %>%
  # make it a data frame
  as.data.frame()
```

And this is the error message:

```
Error: '\(' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\("
```

I find it puzzling because the regex should be correct (cf. https://regex101.com/r/3hbZ0R/1). I've also tried escaping the escapes (e.g., `\\(`) to no avail. I would really appreciate any ideas on how to improve my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work, you have to understand how tokenisation works in **quanteda** and how `pattern` works with multi-token sequences.

First, tokenisation (by default) removes the whitespace that you are including in your regex pattern. But for your pattern, this is not the important part; rather, the sequence is the important part.  Also, the current default tokeniser will split parentheses from the POS tags and text. So you want to control this by using a different tokeniser that splits on (and removes) whitespace.  See `?tokens` and `?pattern`.

Second, to match sequences of tokens, you need to wrap your multi-token pattern in `phrase()`, which will split it on whitespace.  See `?phrase`.

So this will work (and very efficiently):

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 3.3.1
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 71.1
#> Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

txt <- "(ROOT (S (NP (PRP It)) (VP (VBZ is) (RB not) (VP (VBN transmitted) (PP (IN from) (: :) (S (VP (VBG giving) (NP (NP (NP (NP (NML (NN blood)"

toks <- tokens(txt, what = "fasterword", remove_separators = TRUE)
print(toks, -1, -1)
#> Tokens consisting of 1 document.
#> text1 :
#>  [1] "(ROOT"        "(S"           "(NP"          "(PRP"         "It))"        
#>  [6] "(VP"          "(VBZ"         "is)"          "(RB"          "not)"        
#> [11] "(VP"          "(VBN"         "transmitted)" "(PP"          "(IN"         
#> [16] "from)"        "(:"           ":)"           "(S"           "(VP"         
#> [21] "(VBG"         "giving)"      "(NP"          "(NP"          "(NP"         
#> [26] "(NP"          "(NML"         "(NN"          "blood)"

kwic(toks, phrase("\\(VP \\(V \\)"), window = 3, valuetype = "regex")
#> Keyword-in-context with 3 matches.                                                                     
#>    [text1, 6:8] (NP (PRP It)) |     (VP (VBZ is)      | (RB not) (VP 
#>  [text1, 11:13]  is) (RB not) | (VP (VBN transmitted) | (PP (IN from)
#>  [text1, 20:22]       (::) (S |   (VP (VBG giving)    | (NP (NP (NP
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note how you do need to double-escape the reserved characters in the regular expression pattern.

<sup>Created on 2023-07-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

R strings seems to parse a double quoted string by checking first if they find
an escaped allowed character that they can substitute the resultant control code.
Since escaped escape is universally recognized to resolve to a single quote literal,
all escapes will resolve after parsing to the  *`raw`*  regex string passed to the function.

So your double quoted string should be `"\\(VP\\h+\\(V\\w*\\h+\\w*\\)"` which gets parsed to  `\(VP\h+\(V\w*\h+\w*\)` which is handed to the stringr function.

```
 library(stringr)
 str_match_all(
 "(ROOT (S (NP (PRP It)) (VP (VBZ is) (RB not) (VP (VBN transmitted) (PP (IN from) (: :) (S (VP (VBG giving) (NP (NP (NP (NP (NML (NN blood)",
 "\\(VP\\h+\\(V\\w*\\h+\\w*\\)" )
```

https://www.mycompiler.io/view/BjjkPXQUNpT

Output

```
 [[1]]
      [,1]                   
 [1,] "(VP (VBZ is)"         
 [2,] "(VP (VBN transmitted)"
 [3,] "(VP (VBG giving)"
```

Each language enforces different parsing rules.
Some will throw an error if an unknown escape sequence is encounterred
like `\(` others will simply strip the escape to this `(` and not tell you about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've used your regex, but I still don't get any hits. The output is: ```[1] docname from    to      pre     keyword post    pattern
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)```

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the problem: Apparently, the `kwic()` function no longer supports spaces (cf. [kwic in quanteda (R) does not identify more than one word in regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710730/kwic-in-quanteda-r-does-not-identify-more-than-one-word-in-regex-pattern)). I've also used the `token()` function before running the search and wrapped the expression in `phrase()`.

Here is the corrected code:

```
library(quanteda)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

rm(list=ls(all=T))

text <- "(ROOT (S (NP (PRP It)) (VP (VBZ is) (RB not) (VP (VBN transmitted) (PP (IN from) (: :) (S (VP (VBG giving) (NP (NP (NP (NP (NML (NN blood)"

text2 <- tokens(text)


kwic_regex <- kwic(
  text2, 
  phrase("\\( VP \\V\\w* \\w* \\w* \\)"), 
  window = 10, 
  separator = " ",
  case_insensitive = F,
  valuetype = "regex") %>%
  as.data.frame(); kwic_regex
```

Output:

```
  docname from to                        pre                  keyword
1   text1   12 17 ROOT ( S ( NP ( PRP It ) )          ( VP ( VBZ is )
2   text1   22 27 ( VP ( VBZ is ) ( RB not ) ( VP ( VBN transmitted )
3   text1   40 45    ( IN from ) ( : : ) ( S      ( VP ( VBG giving )
                                 post                      pattern
1 ( RB not ) ( VP ( VBN transmitted ) \\( VP \\V\\w* \\w* \\w* \\)
2            ( PP ( IN from ) ( : : ) \\( VP \\V\\w* \\w* \\w* \\)
3           ( NP ( NP ( NP ( NP ( NML \\( VP \\V\\w* \\w* \\w* \\)
```